# Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении. Проблемы с союзными словами

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите разобраться. Есть два предложения: "Сегодня мы узнаем, какие книги, кто читает." и "Не твое дело, какие вещи кто носит.". Правильно ли я понимаю, что в первом случае запятая перед "кто" нужна, так как в предложении утверждается, что станет известно и какие именно книги читают, и кто именно их читает. Во втором же предложении, если оно выражает протест против навязывания всем единого стиля одежды, "кто" скорее является местоимением, нежели союзным словом, поэтому запятая перед ним не нужна. Может быть, есть какое-то общее правило для таких языковых конструкций или все-таки постановка запятой зависит от смыслового содержания предложения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обоих случах это СПП, запятая нужна. В этих примерах "кто" является относительным местоимением, которое выполняет роль союзного слова.

Запятая не ставится,если придаточная часть усечена до одного союзного слова (одиночно употребленное союзное слово теряет функцию придаточного предложения):

Со стороны проспекта кто-то шел — издали было неясно **кто** (Пелев.).

в цельных по смыслу придаточных:

спрятались **кто** куда успел; выдумывали **кто** во что горазд;сделать **как** следует (как полагается, как подобает), выполнить **как** должно (как надо, как нужно), В этих случаях цельные по смыслу выражения эквиваленты члены предложению, поэтому запятая не ставится. **Что нельзя сказать о ваших примерах.**

Answer (score 0):

Ой-ё! Да в обоих предложениях не нужна запятая перед "кто", назови его хоть местоимением, хоть союзным словом! Кто что читает; кто какие книги читает, - ничего не надобно.

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что в первом случае запятая перед "кто" нужна,
>   так как в предложении утверждается, что станет известно и какие именно
>   книги читают, и кто именно их читает.

А где сказано, что книги читают? Может, продают-покупают?

По смыслу именно кто какие читает.